# Capital Gains Tax - Does this apply only to the actual "gains" or to the entire amount of my sale?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, investing, capital-gain

If I buy 10 shares of stock at $10 each I have spent $100 in stocks.

If I later sell these within the same year, do I pay taxes only on the difference of the buy price and the sell price [with a deduction for loss] or the entire amount?

If I buy $100 worth of stock, and then sell it later in the year at $110, do I pay capital gains of 15% on $10? Or do I pay 15% on the $110? (I make under $100k a year)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You normally only pay taxes on the difference between the sale price and the [cost basis](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/costbasis.asp) of the asset. In your example, you would probably pay taxes on the $10 difference, *not* the full sale price of $110. If you paid a commission, however, you would be taxed on your gain minus the commission you paid. Since you held the asset for less than a year, you wouldn't pay the [long-term capital gains rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_gains_tax_in_the_United_States) of 20%; you'd be taxed on the capital gain as if it were ordinary income, which depends on your federal income tax bracket.

Also, littleadv makes a good point about [the implications of buying the asset with after-tax funds](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/23100/7590) too, so that's another part of the equation to consider as well.

Comment: Though the commissions on the trade do affect the basis possibly.  Instead of being taxed on all $100 in gains, it is that minus the commissions for the transactions.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you bought the stocks with after-tax money, you only pay tax on the difference. Had you bought he shares in a pretax retirement account, such as an IRA or 401(k), the taxation waits until you withdraw, at which point, it's all taxed as ordinary income.

Comment: I added a line to continue your thought, you are welcome to re-edit to add or clarify as you wish.

Comment: NP. It looked like you were going there, and got interrupted.

Comment: As a minor clarification and emendation, if the stocks were bought and sold in a **Roth** IRA account, then they _were_ purchased with _after-tax money_ and the capital gains _stay_ in the Roth IRA account and are _not_ taxed when they are ultimately withdrawn, unless the withdrawal is premature and does not meet any of the exceptions that exempt premature withdrawals from tax.